# Atata - Timed out waiting for the jQuery AJAX call to complete

Tags: c#, ajax, ui-automation, atata

I was faced with an issue, when used `[WaitForJQueryAjax]` trigger. The thing is, too much time need to wait for. Is it possible to extend the time frame for this trigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch. I will definitely add `Timeout` property to `[WaitForJQueryAjax]` and similar triggers in the next 0.17.0 version of Atata.

For now, you can extend global retry timeout:

```
AtataContext.Configure().
    // ...
    UseRetryTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)). // Default value is 5 seconds.
    Build();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Yevgeniy. I will wait for updates. For the record, the Atata is a masterpiece)) Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.